# How to display all pages in wordpress site

Tags: php, wordpress, function

How do I get wordpress to automatically paste in the pages names and then their links in the anchor tags?

```
<header>

    <div class="container">

        <div class="header-left">

            <a href="<?php echo get_option('home'); ?>"><h1><?php echo $blog_title = get_bloginfo('name'); ?></h1></a>

            <h2><?php echo get_bloginfo ( 'description' );  ?></h2>

        </div>

        <div class="header-right">

            <a href="<?php ** Page Link Here ** ?>" class="header-link"><?php ** Page Name Here ** ?></a>
            <a href="<?php ** Page Link Here ** ?>" class="header-link"><?php ** Page Name Here ** ?></a>
            <a href="<?php ** Page Link Here ** ?>" class="header-link"><?php ** Page Name Here ** ?></a>
            <a href="<?php ** Page Link Here ** ?>" class="header-link"><?php ** Page Name Here ** ?></a>

        </div>

    </div>

</header>
```

Thanks

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Use the [get_pages](https://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/get_pages)  function of wordpress.

```
<div class="header-right">
<?php
$pages = get_pages();
foreach ( $pages as $page ) {
?><a href="<?php echo get_page_link( $page->ID ) ?>" class="header-link"><?php echo $page->post_title ?></a><?php 
}
?>
```

Comment: Not to detract from the fact that is a fully functional solution, but maybe [wp_list_pages](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/wp_list_pages) might be better for this.